# Change 3rd Party Chromium Plugin Policy?

Tags: chromium, plugins

I use a few plugins on Chromium that are 3rd party (And not on the Plugin Store). They start as disabled when I boot Chromium and I have to go to extensions and re enable them. Is there any way to stop this type of behavior and have the plugins keep the same state that they were before when the browser closes (Enabled)?